# Coin collision detection using cocos2d+box2d - contact listener or custom?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm making an iOS game using cocos2d with Box2D and I'm wondering how to best handle collisions with collectable objects such as coins.  The player is a dynamic body but coins and other collectables will (usually) be static bodies.  Would it be better to create contact listeners between the player and these objects or just iterate over each coin in the game loop (ruling out any coins that are off screen, etc.) and perform circular collision detection on them?

The latter solution seems reasonable to me but I'm inexperienced with box2D and unsure what the advantages/disadvantages and performance costs are when using contact listeners, so I'm not sure if that may be better.

Comment: both work fine, which is better is hard to say and as long as you get a constant 60 fps it eoesn't really matter

Comment: @LearnCocos2D would you recommend either one for the sake of code simplicity?  My first guess is that custom collision detection may be simpler because I could deal directly with the CCPhysicsSprite objects rather than the b2Body objects.

Comment: @stackunderflow it may depend on how many coins there are but I would let the contact listener do it's job.  It seems a little redundant to perform your own collision detection when Box2D is already doing it.  Just keep the code you add in the contact listener to a minimum (as you would in your custom collision detection).  Can't you access the CCPhysicsSprite through bodyDef.userData?

Comment: @Pat Isn't it bad design to have the sprite holding a reference to the body and the body also retaining a reference to the sprite though?

Comment: @stackunderflow The userData is a week reference. It doesn't really know or care about what you passed in.  It's the contact listener that casts it to your object type. From the Box2D documentations: `User data is a void pointer. This gives you a hook to link your application objects to bodies. You should be consistent to use the same object type for all body user data.`  If you really don't like doing it, create a parent object with a CCSprite and b2body members and use the parent object to sync them. The userData would then point to the parent object.

Comment: @Pat Thanks for your input.  If you compile your posts from these comments into an answer, I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: There is interest answers on this question [in this topic](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49345/box2d-do-these-simple-objects-need-to-be-in-the-simulation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would let the contact listener do it's job and not try to implement collision detection in parallel to what Box2D is already doing.

You can use bodyDef.userData to store a week reference to the CCPhysicsSprite object (or a parent object) so that you have access to it in the contact listener.
From the Box2D documentations:

> User data is a void pointer. This gives you a hook to link your application objects to bodies. You should be consistent to use the same object type for all body user data.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at sensors because you do not want coins to stop you in your tracks.

Comment: Yes, the coins are flagged `coinBody.isSensor = true;` but this doesn't really address the question.

Comment: You should probably use the contact listener.